# Are religious people happier?

Tags: psychology, religion, happiness

[This](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v4Mf33RGS5Q&feature=feedrec_grec_index) video discusses the idea that **religious people are happier**.

Are there:

- any sources that support or contradict the claims?
- any scientific papers that address the issue?

Comment: Actually it would be a better summary to say that somebody makes a claim that religious people are happier and the video debunks the idea

Comment: @apoorv020: The video actually does not debunk, it talks about ways to debunk.

Comment: It's going to be tough as "happiness" can't be really measured...

Comment: Interesting question. I once asked on atheism.stack (when it still existed) whether atheists were more prone to suicide. Didn't really get a satisfactory answer. But there is a good way to measure happiness (@Sklivvz)

Comment: 1) How to measure happiness? 2) Bias: As soon as people get the clue that you're interested in investigating a possible correlation, they will answer that, yes, they're indeed very happy with their religion, or that they're indeed very happy without any religion. 3) A higher correlation between atheism and suicide wouldn't mean that atheism makes them unhappier, in the same way that the recent suicides by homosexual teenagers where not due to homosexuality itself, but to society's negative reaction towards it.

Comment: I tend to be extraordinarily happy according to all my peers including the religious ones - and a devout atheist, of the Douglas Adams and Chris Hitchens school. Not certain that means all atheists are happy, but it sure shows I'm happier than a good number of religious folks. Argument either way = zero :-)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Happiness_economics

Comment: are happy people religious?

Comment: @justin: That is really interesting to think about!

Comment: I have a theory that happiness is based entirely on internal factors rather than external ones. I further theorize that it is based entirely on one internal factor: choice. This seems to be the "message" in every Disney movie. Maybe they are on to something.

*Edit-* To answer the question: no (at least not based on my theory, which unfortunately I cannot prove).

Comment: I saw a study mentioned that religious people ho had jobs were happier than non-religious people, but religious people without jobs were unhappier. :) It's probably a complex question.

Comment: Not everyone might have the ability to be made felt happy by a religion. If someone has neither religious experiences nor any belief that "the universe makes sense", it'll be hard for that person to believe. So keep in mind that for those people, this question is inapplicable. For many other people, the question might be relevant, though.

Comment: Religious people worry less and [by implication](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=d-diB65scQU) are more happy. Whether that's a good thing or not is debatable.

Comment: @Lagerbaer 3) That is the same thing. I do not think the question asked or really any useful or interesting questions are does Atheism/homosexuality make you unhappy in a vacuum of nothingness with no access to people, things, or ideas. But how does atheism/homosexuality react to real world conditions.

Comment: @Lagerbaer cont.)It is impossible to measure anything in a void all we can say about anything is that drinking and then driving in our universe, in country, on our roads, while being a human causes more accidents. Similarly all we can say about atheism/homosexuality is that in our current world it is correlated to happiness, sadness, or there has been no significant measurable differences found.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It depends on where you look.  And exactly as people have said, what defines happiness.

[According to some studies](http://www.dailygalaxy.com/my_weblog/2008/03/are-religious-p.html), religious people tend to be happier.

> Researchers accidentally discovered that people with religious beliefs tend to be more content in life while studying an unrelated topic. While not the original objective, the recent European study found that religious people are better able to cope with shocks such as losing a loved one or getting laid off of a job.

But then you look at overall country happiness, and very secular, irreligious nations like [the Scandinavian nations are rated as the happiest](http://www.forbes.com/2010/07/14/world-happiest-countries-lifestyle-realestate-gallup.html).

> "The Scandinavian countries do really well," says Jim Harter, a chief scientist at Gallup, which developed the poll. "One theory why is that they have their basic needs taken care of to a higher degree than other countries. When we look at all the data, those basic needs explain the relationship between income and well-being."

I think it is safe to say that religiousness may not be the main factor in determining happiness, **rather other factors**, and the correlation is incidental.  People searching for a specific correlation and causation will find what they are looking for.  In general, a cum hoc ergo propter hoc fallacy at work in both cases.

For instance, in the religious community, there is a [ready made support structure in place for religious people](http://news.discovery.com/human/religion-happiness-social-bonds.html).

> It's not their spirituality, belief in heaven, or even the ritual act of praying or going to a house of worship that leads the pious to happiness. Rather, the study found, it's the close friends people gain through their religions that makes a difference.

This may be a bigger contributor to happiness than religion or no-religion.

Comment: My small problem with this post is that, you are saying that other factors are probably more important. But what if those parameters are a constant? Are the religious in Scandinavia happier than the non-religious?

Comment: It depends on where you look, and how you look (as I said in the answer).  Anecdotally, the deeply religious people I met in Scandinavia were less happy, because they saw the society they were living in as not meeting up to their expectations and dogmas.

Comment: id argue religious people may be more likely to report being happy, whether they are or not. Not to insinuate anything about religious people generally, but, people tend to respond to surveys by reporting what they think the best answer is, not the honest answer. People may over report their religious commitment and happiness levels in non-random ways.

Comment: the missing counterfactual dooms this sort of analysis to speculation.  We can't compare aggregate happiness levels in scandinavia to a more religious version of scandinavia, nor is there a 'natural experiment' to ferret out the causation. I'd love to see that paper though.

Comment: With such a generic and subjective term as "happy" I can't possibly see any other answer than "it depends".

Comment: @justin cress:  Why wouldn't atheists overreport their happiness, rather than only religious people?

Comment: @David, I would think it's an "expectation" thing.

Comment: @David, they might.  I'm not saying religious people always over report their happiness, i'm just saying if a person over reports his/her happiness, he/she is likely to also over report their religiosity, especially if questions are phrased 'how many times... attend religious service in last X weeks', or 'rate your commitment to..' 'strong, very strong' et cetera

Comment: Maybe Larian has a point regarding the religious people in Scandanavia. Maybe atheists are less happy because they are in a societies dominated by religion?

Comment: Americans seem to think every country that doesn't have a massive ultra-right-wing Christian political contingent is a "very secular, irreligious nation". Scandanavia is a for more religious place than North Korea. Your assumption that some of the wealthiest, most educated, most culturally homogenous countries on earth are happy because they aren't religious is a stretch at best.

Answer (score 6):

Yes, according to [this study](http://www.informaworld.com/smpp/content~db=all~content=a914111234) and [this book](http://books.google.com/books?id=uoD1Ly9CeRAC&printsec=frontcover) (see chapter 16), religiosity correlates with happiness, though it may be religious attendance and not religious belief that really matters ([Chida et al. 2009](http://linkinghub.elsevier.com/retrieve/pii/S027795360900392X)).

There are many factors that correlate with happiness, and there are effective methods to become happier - religious or not.  For more info, and a ton of references, read [How to Be Happy](http://lesswrong.com/lw/4su/how_to_be_happy/) (free online).

> <sub>Sources, in case the links
>   break: 1) Religiosity, subjective
>   well-being, and neuroticism, Mental
>   Health, Religion & Culture, Volume 13,
>   Issue 1, 2010, Pages 67-79. 2) The
>   science of subjective well-being By
>   Michael Eid, Randy J. Larsen. 3)
>   Association between attendance at
>   religious services and self-reported
>   health in 22 European countries,
>   Social Science & Medicine, Volume 69,
>   Issue 4, August 2009, Pages 519-528.</sub>

Comment: Raw correlations are meaningless on a question like this, especially if we're interested in causation. Any number of hypothetical covariates could drive a correlation between reported religiosity and well-being. (Income, family/domestic environment, urban vs. rural residence... to name a few). I can't imagine a natural experiment which would provide the instrument needed for this regression

Answer (score 3):

To add to Larian LaQuella’s answer, [this recent study](http://dx.doi.org/10.1177/0956797611427045)¹ investigated the impact of the a country’s religiosity on the psychological benefits of being religious. In brief, they used data gathered from an online-dating site and investigated the correlations between social self-esteem or psychological adjustment on the one hand and religiosity on the other hand in some European countries. They mainly found positive correlations but these in turn were correlated with the religiosity of the respective country, with the correlations being very low or non-existant, e.g., in Sweden. They conclude:

> Overall, believers claimed greater social self-esteem and
>   psychological adjustment than nonbelievers did. However,
>   culture qualified this effect. Believers enjoyed psychological
>   benefits in countries that tended to value religiosity, but did
>   not differ from nonbelievers in countries that did not tend to
>   value religiosity.

[Another study](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/s10943-013-9739-5)² reports that it failed to replicate this effect:

> Analysis of data from the European Social Survey revealed no significant interactions between country-level religiosity and individual religiosity in predicting psychological well-being.

Unfortunately I do not have access to this paper to provide further details.

---

<sup>¹ Gebauer et al., *Psychological Science* 23.2 (2012): 158–160.

² Pirutinsky, *Journal of Religion and Health* 52.3 (2013): 782–784.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of studies and peer-reviewed books (e.g. Norris and Inglehart, [*Sacred and Secular: Religion and Politics Worldwide*](http://www.cambridge.org/au/academic/subjects/politics-international-relations/comparative-politics/sacred-and-secular-religion-and-politics-worldwide-2nd-edition); Stolt *et al*, [Economic Inequality, Relative Power, and Religiosity](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/j.1540-6237.2011.00777.x/abstract)) which identify a link between religiosity and material insecurity. If you live in a place where with harsher poverty, or which is more economically unequal, then religiosity tends to be higher.

There are some notable exceptions, such as China and Vietnam, which have harsh poverty but low religiosity. This can be explained by the government effectively suppressing religion.

It explains what we see Scandinavia: there is no need for religiosity since those societies are fairly equal. It also explains the United States, which is [one of the most economically unequal developed countries in the world](https://www.cia.gov/library/publications/the-world-factbook/rankorder/2172rank.html). In fact, it's even true of individual states in the US: states with higher economic inequality tend to be more religious, and states with lower economic inequality tend to be less so.

So it seems like a plausible theory that if things are bad, religion helps you cope with it. Opiate of the masses, indeed.